# How can I save the value returned for an CompletionHandler?

Tags: swift3, completionhandler

I have the next function that make an http request with completionhandler and receives a json response:

```
func makeRequest3(request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (JSON!)->Void){
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ data, response, error in
        //Code

        print(data as NSData)
        let json = JSON(data: data)

        completion(json)

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I need to call this function , and find the "id_token" field for save it in a variable. Im beginner and im trying this code, but i have the error "Type '()' has no subscript members"

```
    var response2 =  makeRequest3(request: request) {response in //<-`response` is inferred as `String`, with the code above.
        return(response)
    }

    var idtoken = response2["id_token"]
```

How i can do it? Im using swift3.

Comment: You can't use `return` as the request will complete asynchronously.  You need to do your work with the token *inside* the closure.

Answer (score 1):

Your `makeRequest3` itself does not return value, but the response is passed to the completion handler, **do all things needed for the response in the completion handler**:

```
makeRequest3(request: request) {response in //<-`response` is inferred as `JSON`, with your `makeRequest3`.
    var idtoken = response["id_token"]
    //Use `idtoken` inside this closure
    //...
}
```